# Get value from txt file

Tags: javascript, file, variables, text, text-files

I have a txt file that I will add value to later on by a .php script, but for now I am looking for a way to get the latest value from a txt file by using javascript, so lets say the lates value has been added and it is 3, I then wan't javascript to get that value and turn the variable in the script into that value.

example of how the txt file will look.
1
2
3

and then because 3 is the lates value added, the javascript variable will get that and turn it into a variable.

So let's say my javascript file looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

                    var nrValue= 1;
                    document.getElementById("nrValue").innerHTML = nrValue;
                    document.getElementByID("nrValue").value = nrValue;

                </script>
```

I then wan't the javascript function to turn the `nrValue` into the latest updated value from the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the .txt file by AJAX call and then process the data in the result. Something like this:

```
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
   // The type o breaking line caracter will vary depending on OS
   var values = data.split("\n");       
   var lastValue = values[values.length-1];              
});
```